# How to login to a protected module view in suitecrm using php curl?

Tags: php, curl, suitecrm

Regards

I am trying to measure the load time of a view of a module in suitecrm. what I expect is to simulate the visit to a specific view by n users and measure their loading time.

The flow that I intend to implement is to access the site providing user and password, doing the above store the session and accessing the module view by n occations, enclose these interactions in microtime and obtain the time that this process takes

The first problem that I am currently facing is that using PHP curl does not manage to loggin into a server in production protected with ssl.

This is the script I am trying

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://site/index.php?action=Login&module=Users');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=user&password=pass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$answer = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_error($curl)) {
    echo curl_error($curl);
}

//another request preserving the session

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://site/index.php?module=Opportunities&offset=1&stamp=1535132707073610600&return_module=Opportunities&action=EditView&record=90eef8e0-e46d-85cc-cef8-5b7e96bd1111');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");

$answer = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_error($curl)) {
    echo curl_error($curl);
}

$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;

echo round($time_elapsed_secs, 2);
```

My problem is that I can not access the site, and consequently the calculated time is only the time delayed in loading the login view

Thanks in advance, if you need more information please let me know to facilitate it

Answer (score 0):

After try and try I got to successfully login into a suitecrm site, I share the solution in case someone needs it

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

$url = 'https://domain/index.php';
$authenticateFields = [
    'action'            => 'Authenticate',
    'cant_login'        => '',
    'Login'             => 'Iniciar+Sesión',
    'login_action'      => '',
    'login_language'    => 'es_ES',
    'login_mobile'      => '',
    'login_module'      => '',
    'login_oauth_token' => '',
    'login_record'      => '',
    'login_token'       => '',
    'module'            => 'Users',
    'return_action'     => 'Login',
    'return_module'     => 'Users',
    'user_name'         => 'your_username',
    'username_password' => 'your_password',
];
$editOpportunityFields = [
    'action'            => 'EditView',
    'module'            => 'Opportunities',
    'offset'            => 1,
    'record'            => '93dbe6a2-fd18-7965-45af-5b72fc8afb96',
    'return_module'     => 'Opportunities',
    'stamp'             => 1535401065081436600,
];
$authenticateFields = http_build_query($authenticateFields);
$editOpportunityFields = http_build_query($editOpportunityFields);
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $authenticateFields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/ip4.x/file/tmp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "?{$editOpportunityFields}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$headers = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

print_r($response);
print_r($headers);
print_r($code);
echo "\n";

$end = microtime(true);
$timeElapsed = $end - $start;

print_r($timeElapsed);

curl_close($curl);
```

In this example, I get to login and after a successfully login I request to the Opportunity edit view and finally print the information in the transfer. In this case the return are the content, headers, http code and loading time elapsed

My problem was not to pass the parameters expected in the login action. After inspecting the form and identifying a series of inputs that are transferred when sending the form and also inspecting the parameters sent during the authentication, I got the fields that suitecrm requires to allow the login

On the issue of measuring the load time, thanks to a response in stackoverflow I managed to identify that it is not possible to obtain real data using phpcurl, for the explanation, please read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3417514/615274).

I appreciate any comments, in order to help anyone who needs respect in this scenario